# Problemas de contenido en Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, nginx, cache

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Mi proyecto Wordpress "oculta" las publicaciones y ediciones en las páginas o noticias que realizo, pero al cabo de un tiempo las mismas aparecen publicadas en la página principal y de repente vuelven a desaparecer...

Ya instalé un plugin para borrar el caché y mi servidor nginx, por defecto, tiene deshabilitado el caching y sigo con el problema.

Alguna idea de lo que puede estar ocurriendo?

Comment: Esto puede ser debido a algún plugin o utro código que gestione las entradas que deben mostrarse en la página principal. Para asegurarte de que tu entrada esté publicad o no, solamente tienes que ver su estado, sea buscándola y abriéndola en modo edición (allí podrás ver si está en estado `Publicado` o  Published` o no) o verificando directamente en la base de datos de Wordpress.

Comment: sospecho que algun plugin te la está jugando.
¿Puedes poner un listado de los plugins empleados?